# Error while Running website on ftp server

Tags: oledb, ftp-server

I have a asp.net Website with msaccess database and c# .The Site run on IIS server Normaly but when i upload it to the ftp server then it display the folowing error

"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

What should i do to resolve the issue

Comment: I assume you run the website locally on IIS with Access and now you try to upload it to your hosting provider by means of FTP and after that you receive the error as described when you hit the 'production' server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be ask the hosting provider to install the Microsoft Access engine on the webserver.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

I'm not sure if you could deploy it with webdeploy. That would enable that you can deploy and install it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This driver is not installed by default and i don't think your service provider is gonna install it specially for you.

You better use mdb files instead of accdb files, and use the Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0 driver instead.

You can use the following tutorial for further reading

[AccessDataSource, SqlDataSource and connecting to Access databases in ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/78/AccessDataSource-SqlDataSource-and-connecting-to-Access-databases-in-ASP.NET)